# How many N-qubit stabilizer states are there?

Tags: stabilizer-state

An N-qubit stabilizer state is a state that can be produced by starting from the $|0\rangle^{\otimes N}$ state and applying only H, CNOT, and S gates. How many N-qubit stabilizer states are there?

Because every stabilizer state can be [represented as a graph states](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504117), which has an edge (or not) between each pair out of N nodes and also one of 24 possible Clifford operations on each node, there are at most $2^{(N^2)} 24^N$ stabilizer states over $N$ qubits. But a stabilizer state can have multiple graph state representations. What's a corresponding lower bound on the stabilizer state count, and what's the exact count?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are $S(n) = 2^n \prod_{i=1}^n (2^i + 1)$ $n$-qubit stabilizer states, as per Corollary 21 of [D. Gross, *Hudson's Theorem for finite-dimensional quantum systems*, J. Math. Phys. 47, 122107 (2006)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0602001).

Here's a simple approximation of $S(n)$:

$$S(n) \approx \sqrt{2}^{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

This approximation is within a factor of 2 of the real anwer for all $n$. It starts too high but by $n=3$ it's a bit too low and as $n$ goes to infinity it limits to being about 20% too low. Multiplying it by 1.192115 gets a much better estimate for large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary $d$ (modular qudits), the number of stabilizer states is seen to scale similarly. [Corollary 1](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2209.01449) says that for $c=2.17$

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:nkd_count_order_states_intro}
   d^{\frac{n(n+3)}{2}} \ \le S(n,d) \ < \ \  d^{\frac{n(n+3)}{2}+c}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0406196.pdf) for Aaronson-Gottesman algorithm, the expression for the number of stabiliser states is given with an accessible proof.

$$ 2^n \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2^{n-k}+1)$$

Thanks to Oscar Higgott for bringing my attention to it.